# Looping when predicting with keras

Tags: python, keras

I created a prediction with keras and I want to see what are results if I repeat the prediction 10 times for example. If I loop I get a warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x1507503a0> triggered tf.function retracing.
```

My question: Is it the same if I loop like this

```
for a in range(1,11):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
    # new instance where we do not know the answer
    Xnew = np.array([[96.52, 114, 111.02, 0.538, 0.559, 0.5082, 0.4992, 96.92, 104.94, 107.38]])
    # make a prediction
    ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
    # show the inputs and predicted outputs
    print("Predicted=%s" % (ynew[0]))
```

or if I output 10 times like this:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    **model.add(Dense(10, activation='linear'))**
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, verbose=0)
    # new instance where we do not know the answer
    Xnew = np.array([[96.52, 114, 111.02, 0.538, 0.559, 0.5082, 0.4992, 96.92, 104.94, 107.38]])
    # make a prediction
    ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
    # show the inputs and predicted outputs
    print("Predicted=%s" % (ynew[0]))
```

I would say it's not the same but I'm new to this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is totally different:

1. In the first case: the model output is only one neuron and in each iteration you build your model from scratch. You should know that this is not a accumulative training meaning not equivalent like you train your model 10000 time. (epochs 10 * for-loop iterations 1000).
2. In the second case: the model output is 10 neurons. Your model is trained 1000 epochs.

The error mentioned arises perhaps it is a TensorFlow problem when you put a model in a loop. You could know more about this issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34025#issuecomment-603711703).